# Error when installing django channels on Fedora 24

Tags: python, django, fedora, django-channels

This is the `error` that comes up when installing `django` channels with `pip install` channels:

```
error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

    ----------------------------------------
Command "/home/arunvm/Desktop/CleverHires/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-oisfgik6/twisted/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-689vby9j-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers /home/arunvm/Desktop/CleverHires/include/site/python3.5/twisted" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-oisfgik6/twisted/
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have Python headers installed.

Please run...

```
>>> sudo yum install python-devel
```

Comment: that didnt work, even after installing python-devel, the error still pops up.

Comment: Use `dnf`. You probably also wanted to write `python3-devel`